# Update BLOB column data

Tags: sql, blob

is it possible to change specific content of BLOB column data?

i.e. I have a table which has a BLOB data type column. It holds some text content.

I want to replace some characters within this text content for a selective set of rows.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

In general yes, but what interface are you using?

See, for example, [this java/jdbc method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#setBytes%28long,%20byte%5B%5D%29)

Comment: I would like to modify through update query, is it possible and my xml is like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.XYZ.org/XMI" xmlns:bpmn="com.test.xyz.bpe.ui.workflow" xmlns:notation="http://www.eclipse.org/gmf/runtime/1.0.1/notation">
  <bpmn:BusinessProcessModel xmi:id="_GSSDFBSNNERND45" name="Event1" description="Event1 - a model" id="-1" modelType="xyzd" subModelType="dim" author="rr" domainGroup="DIM/Success" companyId="22" status="Active" rank="3" language="XML" expressionLanguage="JQL"> ..........

Comment: Here "companyId" value would have to replace with "0", irrespective of it's current value.